# Add Dock to second monitor on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, dock

Is it at all possible to add a dock to a second monitor on Mac OS X? If so, how?

Comment: Add a Dock, as in have two Docks, or move the Dock to the second monitor?

Comment: Presumably it's have two Docks, since he says "add".

Comment: Yes, add another.

Comment: OS X just isn't designed in a way which is friendly to multiple displays. :/

Comment: This still hasn't happened, and sucks. Two docks seems like something simple - not for MAC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No.

At least not native. OS X ties the menu bar and dock to one "main" monitor and uses the second as secondary displays.

Comment: Well, I have this app called SecondBar that (kind of) allows the menu bar to go to a secondary monitor, maybe there is something for the Dock?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: This is poor; Apple should implement this. Is the a way to request it from them?

Answer (score 3):

this will not add a second dock to your display, however it will move the dock to the second monitor.  How? go to System Pref->Displays->Arrangement then move the second monitor below the main one, so when refreshed your dock appears on your second display ( notably the screen position is bottom ) hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too picky with the task bar being on the far right, I find setting the "position on screen" to "right" will move the dock to the second screen, WAY over to the right of my workspace. Not a BIG deal for me, some I imagine would get annoyed I would guess. For me I use the dock mostly for monitoring what my Mac is up to and use a mouse button to jump between apps. Is an option. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Dock-It gives you a second configurable dock. Not as intuitive as the Mac doc, but once you've added your items via the interface, you have a hiding dock.

Answer (score 1):

[Secondbar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) for a second menu bar and Yahoo widget engine with [WidgDock](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19175/widgdock) for a second customizable dock.

I love both apps – they work perfectly and are free.

Answer (score 1):

On High Sierra, the only way I got it to be on the left on my second monitor was, with the dock set to appear at the bottom (that's the only position it would show on the second monitor), I moved the menu bar in Preferences > Displays > Arrangement to that monitor (by grabbing it), then when I changed the position of the dock to the left it finally appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DragThing](http://dragthing.com/english/about.html). I haven't used it myself in a long time, but back when I did, it could create docks with almost any layout and function you wanted. It's not exactly the Mac OS X Dock in the sense of having minimized windows and so on, but it may serve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of OS X you are running (Mavericks and later), you can mouse over where the dock would be on another screen and it should appear there.

Comment: This does not work (at least if the dock is located on the side instead of bottom) (10.14.x)